# JavaScript variable value gets overwritten when checking for "undefined"

Tags: javascript, if-statement, overriding, undefined, variable-declaration

I have a function that gets called in two different scenarios. 
**Scenario 1** gets triggered by a dropbown selection, and I set the variable *"sheetName"* based on the selected value. 
**Scenario** 2 doesn't have a trigger event, so I want to set the variable further down in my code when I gathered the other information I need in order to set the value.

Now here's my problem: When **Scenario 1** occurs, *sheetName* gets defined and the function proceeds. But with the code below, *sheetName* appears to be **undefined** as soon as it reaches the **if condition** for the second code. So the value gets **overwritten** here because the program thinks, *sheetName* is undefined.

Whenever I remove the **if condition** for the **second** scenario everything works fine and *sheetName* has the correct value I defined earlier in the code.

I can't define the two values within an if/else statement because for the first scenario I need the **oEvent** and for the second scenario I need the **wb** data..
Why does the if condition remove the value of my variable? Am I checking incorrectly?

Please let me know if you need anything else!

```
 onSheetSelected : function(oEvent) {
        var file = sap.ui.getCore()._file;
        var oTable = this.getView().byId('uploadData');
// Sheet name gets defined for Scenario 1       
        if(oEvent !== undefined) {              
            var sheetName = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem().getText();
        }
        if(file && window.FileReader){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var result = {}, data;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var rawLog = reader.result;
                data = e.target.result;
                var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary', cellDates: true, cellText: false, cellNF: true});
// Sheetname gets defined for Scenario 2
                if(sheetName === undefined) {
                    var sheetName = wb.SheetNames[0];   
                }
                var worksheet = wb.Sheets[sheetName];
                        ... some other stuff going on...
            }.bind(this);
        };
    },
```

Comment: You're re-declaring the variable, in Scenario 2, remove the `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into this issue due to [JavaScript Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) the variable where you're re-declaring it in the second scenario

```js
function thing1() {
  var sheetname = "this"
  //this will look at thing1.sheetname
  console.log(sheetname)

  function thing2() {
    // this will look at thing2.sheetname
    if (sheetname === undefined) {
      var sheetname = "that"
    }
    console.log(sheetname)
  }
  thing2()
}

thing1()
```

But by removing the `var` it will look up until it can find a variable called `sheetname`

```js
function thing1() {
  var sheetname = "this"
  //this will look at thing1.sheetname
  console.log(sheetname)

  function thing2() {
    // this will look at thing1.sheetname
    if (sheetname === undefined) {
      sheetname = "that"
    }
    console.log(sheetname)
  }
  thing2()
}

thing1()
```